# In Play Framework can you get the remote port of the request?

Tags: playframework, httprequest

I have a Play server (v2.4.6) in Scala handling REST requests, and I can get the IP of the client making the REST call, but I see no way to get the remote port.  This is possible in a Servlet HttpRequest.

I know someone is going to ask why I need such a thing.  The short answer is that the Play server is hit not by browsers but by custom applications, and the Play server, aside from handling REST calls, must also broker these applications so they can talk to each other peer-to-peer using NAT punching and I could kill two birds with one stone if only I could get the remote port of the request.

Comment: I don't know with a built-in function in Play!, but you could use (as a workaround) Akka cluster and create an actor that give you the address with Cluster(context.system).system.provider.getDefaultAddress.toString

Comment: The client is a C++ application, and one that must run on OSX, iOS, Windows, and Android.  Wouldn't I have to find a C++ Akka library and incorporate it?  I don't know if that would be quicker than just doing it all myself (writing a thread to handle clients sending UDP packets and noting their remote port).

Comment: Add to your question the version of Play Framework you are using

Comment: @RoAnders No, you will only have to add Akka cluster to your application, i.e add some imports in your build.sbt and create your actor (10-20 lines) but there is probably an easier solution.